# Delphi XE2, Delphi 10 Seattle, Application Handle, Dll, Action Error

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-10-seattle

I have App.exe applications created in Delphi XE2, then the DLL is created in Delphi 10 Seattle. When I pass an Application.Handle to a DLL after calling a DLL I get an error "Exception class .... 'floating point stack check ...'". When I remove the Application.Handle from EXE assignment, the DLL is ok. I noticed this is related to the TAction action that is hooked to controlek. Eg to MainMenu. I'll also add that when a DLL is called from an EXE that is written in Delphi 10 Seattle it's all ok.

Thank you for your help.

Below I attach some code

Code Delphi XE2

```
unit Form_MainApp;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Buttons;

type
  TfrmMainApp = class(TForm)
    btnRunDLL: TBitBtn;
    procedure btnRunDLLClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public

  end;

var
  frmMainApp: TfrmMainApp;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfrmMainApp.btnRunDLLClick(Sender: TObject);
const
  LibraryFolder = '\Library\';
    DLLName = LibraryFolder + 'TestDLL.dll';
type
  TDLLProc = Function(pAppHandle:HWND; pAppTitle:PChar; pId:Integer; var pOUTId:Integer): TModalResult; StdCall;
var
  DLLHandle: THandle;
    DLLProc: TDLLProc;
  DLLResult: TModalResult;
  OUTId: Integer;
  LibraryName: String;
begin
  LibraryName:=ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName) + DLLName;
  DLLHandle:=Winapi.Windows.LoadLibrary(PChar(LibraryName));
    try
    if DLLHandle <> 0 then
      begin
        @DLLProc:=Winapi.Windows.GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, PChar('Run_TestDLL'));
        if (@DLLProc <> nil) then
          DLLResult:=DLLProc(Application.Handle, PChar(Application.Title), 0, OUTId);
      end;
    finally
    if DLLHandle <> 0 then
      Winapi.Windows.FreeLibrary(DLLHandle);
    end;
end;

end.
```

Code Delphi 10 Seattle

```
library TestDLL;

  uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  Controls,
  Forms,
  Dialogs,
  Windows,
  Form_MainDLL in 'Form_MainDLL.pas' {frmMainDLL};

{$R *.res}

Function Run_TestDLL(pAppHandle:HWND; pAppTitle:PChar; pId:Integer; var pOUTId:Integer):TModalResult; StdCall;
begin
  Application.Handle:=pAppHandle;
    Result:=mrNone;
  try
    frmMainDLL:=TfrmMainDLL.Create('Test');
    frmMainDLL.ShowModal;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(frmMainDLL);
      Result:=mrOk;
  end;
end;

exports
  Run_TestDLL;
begin
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown:=True;
  Randomize;
end.
```

FORM in DLL

```
unit Form_MainDLL;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  cxEdit, dxBar, Vcl.ExtCtrls, System.Actions,
  Vcl.ActnList, Vcl.Menus, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TfrmMainDLL = class(TForm)
    mmMain: TMainMenu;
    mmEdit: TMenuItem;
    mmAdd: TMenuItem;
    mmData: TMenuItem;
    mmClose: TMenuItem;
    mmOpen: TMenuItem;
    btnSetAction: TButton;
    alMain: TActionList;
    acAdd: TAction;
    procedure acAddExecute(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnSetActionClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    fName: String;
  public
    constructor Create(pName:String);reintroduce; virtual;
    destructor Destroy; Override;
  end;

var
  frmMainDLL: TfrmMainDLL;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

constructor TfrmMainDLL.Create(pName:String);
begin
  inherited Create(Nil);
  fName:=pName;
end;

destructor TfrmMainDLL.Destroy;
begin

  inherited;
end;

procedure TfrmMainDLL.acAddExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('TEST');
end;

procedure TfrmMainDLL.btnSetActionClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  mmAdd.Action:=acAdd;
  mmAdd.OnClick:=acAddExecute;
end;


end.
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Comment: I managed to add some code. I have prepared a simple example.

Comment: The DLL is a form that only has TMainMenu, TActionList. MainMenu is connected to the action. Attempting to run this action causes an error.

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. Please try again.

Comment: Maybe you will tell me what I have to prepare you to look at the problem?

Comment: I have never posted code examples here.

Comment: Follow the link I have posted twice and read carefully.

Comment: I've minimized the code in both projects that are needed to address the problem. Do I have to code all these projects?

Comment: Did you follow the link?

Comment: Yes, I think I've left the complete minimum code that generates the problem.

Comment: No. This can't be compiled. Keep trying.

Comment: Now show the correct code.

Comment: I can't reproduce, but I don't have those exact versions to hand. I've got XE3 for the app and XE7 for the DLL. That's as close as I can readily get.

Comment: Does it work on the versions listed?

Comment: When you launch the form from the DLL, you must click 'Set Action' and then click on the edit-> add menu.

Comment: Sure, I get that. I just don't have your specific versions to hand. I would not be surprised if there were other settings that mattered. Did you build the test environment from scratch? Or did you cut down an existing project?

Comment: Both test projects have been made from the ground up.

Comment: Have you clicked on the dll form action?

Comment: Thanks for working on the question.  You've done a really good job. Unfortunately I just cannot go any further without those specific versions to hand. I might be able to do more at a different machine. But for now that's all I can manage. Hope somebody else can chip in.

Comment: Restore the application.handle in Run_TestDLL before leaving the function

Comment: In normal code is a function that inverts the assignment of Application.Handle at the output of the DLL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that messages `CM_ACTIONEXECUTE` and `CM_ACTIONUPDATE` will not be sent from VCL code in DLL to VCL code in EXE (because they have different runtime, and different TAction objects).

There are several ways:

1. Hook window procedure for TApplication.Handle window and filter messages.
   For example see HookApplication and UnhookApplication at:
   https://github.com/achechulin/loodsman/blob/master/Loodsman/Loodsman.Infrastructure.PluginUtils.pas
2. Add OnUpdate and OnExecute handlers to all TAction objects.
3. Do not use TAction at all.

Also, you need to catch all exceptions in Run_TestDLL.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your help. I applied solution 2 and it works.
So in normal code I have to create a method for OnUpdate for all actions.
For solution 1 I would have to read a little. So far I do not know exactly where I would have to make the suggested changes? Could you write more about this (send)? I will try to integrate the DXE2 version of the system with the new modules written in D10Seattle, and I expect that I can still find some interesting cases.

Comment: I would like to ask why this is the case for the compilation (in my case) in these two different compilers. (Exe in DXE2, dll in D10Seattle). Where exe and dll is compiled in the same compilers everything is ok.

Comment: Basic principle: you cannot pass objects, strings (except of WideString), dynamic arrays between EXE and DLL.

To have a possibility of pass strings/dynamic arrays you need to use shared memory manager.

To have a possibility of pass objects you need to use packages.

Comment: CM_ACTIONEXECUTE and CM_ACTIONUPDATE pass TAction object from DLL to EXE runtime.

Comment: I know and I try to apply the "basic principle". About memory managers I know too. Unfortunately, I can not use packages.

Comment: CM_ACTIONEXECUTE and CM_ACTIONUPDATE pass TAction object from DLL to EXE. I understand that the transfer of TAction is intentional (is it a little unhappy here)? Is the error stemming from different TAction definitions between Delphi versions?

Comment: Yes, there is System.Actions unit in newest Delphi versions, and TAction was changed.